# Django:permission denied for relation django_migrations, PostgreSql - django user?

Tags: python, linux, django, postgresql

I ve been struggling about figuring out relation between postgre users and linux users and the permissions between them.First question I want to ask is that ,let s assume I have tom linux user and tom postgre user which I created with psql command.What is the relation between those two? The reason I am asking is realated with following question:

I am using vagrant and ubuntu in it.There is 2 userss , first one is `Linux` "vagrant" user , second one is `PostgreSql` "vagrant" user which I created through following commands:

```
CREATE USER vagrant WITH PASSWORD '123.123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE cashier to vagrant;
```

which should means and also is that vagrant have all permissions on cashier database.

I should also mention as an aside note that I am using provisioning and vagrant uses root user when executing provisions , so root should also have all permissions on the cashier databse because I am importing dump into cashier database on provisioning.

so you can easily assume root have granted permissions through :

```
CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD 'vagrant';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE cashier to root;
```

Here is the problem: When I try to runserver  in django python manage.py runserver

if I go with the following settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'cashier',
    'USER': 'vagrant',
    'PASSWORD': '123.123',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

I get authentication error, and if I go with the following settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'cashier',
    'USER': 'vagrant',
    'PASSWORD': 'vagrant',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

Then i have Django:permission denied for relation django_migrations, problem.Simply my question is What is going on?What is the  relation between users?Which user should i use ? Why django cant migrate with both user credentials?

Recall : 
Linux user vagrant pass vagrant
Postgre user vagrant pass 123.123

Comment: to know whether the same name is creating problem or not, just try to create a user with different name in psql and try to migrate with that user and password and check whether you face the same problem, if no then i guess you cannot have the same name, if problem persists then there is some problem with connector

Comment: on the linux shell as user `vagrant` try an `psql -h localhost -U vagrant vagrant` to check if you can connect to the db

Comment: after running  psql -h localhost -U vagrant cashier command and then typing the password "vagrant"  yes i can be prompt into cashier db.

Comment: hmm .. have you tried to create a different database user eg "dbvagrant" and use this one as Exprator suggested. That would be my guess too now. Postgres can be configured to rely on the system password. There is some possible confusion there

Comment: by the way when i dump into db it gives warnings at the end     
    WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
`WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"`

Comment: Try changing the HOST definition to localhost. There could be an issue with address resolution.

Comment: It is also wierd that when i manually dump the db into new one.Everything works fine.Maybe problem is I am trying to dump the files into with different user rather then django uses even though i gave the all permissions both users.I dont know for sure.

Comment: @user37821do you have any updates on this one?